# API not loading into console

Tags: jquery, ajax, response

Im trying to pull data from CNet's api, the api being pulled to the web page, because when I inspect the elements, the response is in the network, however it is not showing in the console.

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://developer.api.cnet.com/rest/v1.0/techProductSearch",
      type: "get",
      data: { viewType:"json", iod: "none", callback: "phone", partKey:"2nnae6wsj2w72yqhcwu4v7sg", partTag:"2nnae6wsj2w72yqhcwu4v7sg", query: "ipod", productId:"31303113" },
      dataType: "jsonp"
    });

});
function ipod(data) {
console.log(data);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: what is `function ipod`? How `$.ajax` is assumed to know about it?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified what to do when jQuery has completed successfully. Execute ipod function I guess; but jQuery can't

So, this should do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
  url: "http://developer.api.cnet.com/rest/v1.0/techProductSearch",
  type: "get",
  data: { viewType:"json", iod: "none", callback: "phone", partKey:"2nnae6wsj2w72yqhcwu4v7sg", partTag:"2nnae6wsj2w72yqhcwu4v7sg", query: "ipod", productId:"31303113" },
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: ipod 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the results of the ajax to a method ..

Use the `.done()` method

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://developer.api.cnet.com/rest/v1.0/techProductSearch",
  type: "get",
  data: { viewType:"json", iod: "none", callback: "phone", partKey:"2nnae6wsj2w72yqhcwu4v7sg", partTag:"2nnae6wsj2w72yqhcwu4v7sg", query: "ipod", productId:"31303113" },
  dataType: "jsonp"
}).done(ipod);
```